# Crystal Reports Running Total not counting correctly

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

My initial issue was that suppressed results were still being added up in my summary.

So I found the Running Total option and thought I was on a winner. However, now it does not seem to be adding all the amounts in the group and only the first result.

[image: Running Total]

I have played with it as much as I can, but either get the suppressed results included or only the first result.

This is how I have the Running Total set up:

[image: Running Total Screen]

I want to summarize the Amount. I am assuming the Evaluate will add the totals showing when the Deal No changes
I am assuming the Running Total will reset when the Deal No changes

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you give me your table structure which used in crystal report and also 2 or 3 line of data of above structure.

Comment: It's because you have got both `Evaluate` and `Reset` on the same field (`cflowrpt.deal_no`). You haven't given us enough information about your data and requirements to be able to tell you which settings you should be using.

Comment: Thanks to both for answering.
Please find a screenshot of structure here: [link](http://i.imgur.com/YTrJgJw.png)

I have circled the Deal No, Amount and RunningTotal fields. The GRNetFigure field is commented out and suppressed so not being used. 

Some data that was produced: [link](http://i.imgur.com/aR9gn31.png)

Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good to solve this issue by yourself. Ok, I try to explain the reason.

Running total is magical field, the reason is if you some thing change in configuration, you either get the result or lost the result. So be care-full with your thoughts while assign fields/columns.

In running total, there are three part as you can see in your image.

1. What to summarize (start with 0)
2. When to summarize (to accumulate with previous value)
3. When to reset (means when to reset to 0 again generally we need for 
   change group or particular primary-key column or other column value will change)

Check this link for more understanding.

[Google book link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=isoPezxjvo8C&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=running%20total%20in%20crystal%20report%20understand&source=bl&ots=aKUllmyPGd&sig=47jG2UBUtKj0AQUPXfFLtKfTlaw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI1IOdm8zcxgIVg1UUCh2wigLS#v=onepage&q&f=false)

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic156.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know why this worked, but evaluating on Change of Field of the Amount and reset on the deal number worked. Not sure how this works because the amount will always change and is what I am summarizing on. But it works so I won't ask questions.

[image: Answer]

Comment: please accept one of those answer to close the question and helpful to some.

Answer (score 0):

One more important point to check:

The running total field is calculated as each record gets printed. So running total field need to *run* through each records before showing the result. That's why its name is '*running* total'.

So if you have put the running total field in group **header** section then it will calculate the result of the first record only. In case you want to calculate for each record of the group, you have to put the field in group **footer** section.

So make sure you have put the summarize field in the correct section.